# Add data to Firebase ID token

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt, token

Is it possible to add small pieces of data to the Firebase ID Token? For example, it seems some fields like uid, email, displayName and phoneNumber are part of it. Could I add firstName and lastName fields too?

The use case is every now and then, I need to access the first and last names of the logged in user. If not the ID token, where else can I store them, if at all?

I was considering storing in custom claims, but it feels like I'd be abusing the feature.

Comment: Also posted on: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/OHy_Oyfr240

Comment: Thanks for cross-referencing @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add fields to an ID token other than what's listed in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.decodedidtoken).  The only way you can provide additional information is through using [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims).  A custom claims payload is [restricted to 1000 bytes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims), so it's not very flexible.

Sometimes it's more appropriate to simply store additional information about the user in a database, keyed off the user's UID.

Comment: Sounds good! I'll evaluate more if custom claims makes sense given the restrictions

Answer (score 2):

You can add personal info to a custom token.
Then, use this custom token for authentication.

Custom token:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

JSON Web Token: 
https://jwt.io/

JSON Web Token for Java and Android
https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt

Comment: So I'm using Google, Facebook and Email/Password as the login mechanisms in my app. From what I can tell, custom tokens are for when you have your own authentication system you want users to go through. So don't think I can use that.